# Infinispan 11.0.9 -rocksdb - Java Process Exit

Tags: wildfly, infinispan

I am using Inifnispan 11.0.9 rocksdb cache store in wildlfy module. I observed that Java process gets exit after add & remove 1K elements in cache. when I checked java process dump logs, I found culprit librocksdbjni14410366623956126638.dll,  I am using default configuration of rocksdb cache store.
Configuration cache -

`

Is it bug ? or Am I doing wrong?

Comment: <local-cache name="Nmae1Cache" statistics="false">
   <locking acquire-timeout="60000" />
   <persistence passivation="false">
    <rocksdb-store path="C:\CacheStore" preload="false" shared="false" purge="false" read-only="false"  >
     <expiration path="C:\CacheStore"/>
       </rocksdb-store>
   </persistence>

Comment: I am using <serialization  marshaller="org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller"> marshaller configuration